# How to make dropdown immediately response base on this js code?

Tags: javascript, html

I found this [original code from other answer(jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/ghLc9/25/) . What it does is, when the user selected `other` from dropdown selection, a textbox will appear. But if i put `<option value='0' selected>Other</option>`, when the page appear for the first time, it doesn't make the textbox appear. How do I solve this?

**Code That I change**

```
<option value='0' selected>Other</option>
```

Comment: You have to call the onchange() when the page is ready. Since the onchange() event is only triggered on actual changes from the user.

Comment: where do I put onchange() at?

Comment: There are various ways, depending on your browser. window.onload() or  a listener on DOMContentLoaded are two ways to do it.

Comment: I'm using chrome

Comment: See here: http://jsfiddle.net/ghLc9/49/ or http://jsfiddle.net/ghLc9/52/

Comment: Nice...works like a charm! I would vote for best answer if you put it on answer box

Comment: Done. Good luck with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call the onchange() when the page is ready. Since the onchange() event is only triggered on actual changes from the user.

Example 1:
[jsfiddle.net/ghLc9/49](http://jsfiddle.net/ghLc9/49)

```
$('select').trigger("change");
```

Example 2:
[jsfiddle.net/ghLc9/52](http://jsfiddle.net/ghLc9/52)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').trigger("change");
})
```

Answer (score 2):

what you can do is to extract the textbox's show/hide logic to a function and call this function when the page loads. This is an example of the updated JS code:

```
var updateMyText = function(){

  var value = $("select").val();

  if( value  == '0')
      $("#myTxt").show();
    else
        $("#myTxt").hide();
}

$('select').on('change', updateMyText)

//Update the UI when the page loads
$(function(){
    updateMyText();
})
```

This is a link to the updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ghLc9/53/

Comment: this is the same issue as @Sanket Dhoble answer

Comment: @learnprogramming It's not. This one is correct (and actually cleaner than accepted solution). Try it by making another option selected.

Comment: @Vasan: Depends on the context. I do not find the use of an own function which is not reusable (no parameters, fixed selector) any usefull in this specific case.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I couldn't comment as my reputation is less.
In Your code,
Write

> $("#myTxt").show() outside the onchange function,

to load the input, when page appears first time.

Here is the fiddle,
http://jsfiddle.net/sanketdhoble/ghLc9/46/

```
$("#myTxt").show();
$('select').on('change', function() {

  if( this.value  == '0')
    $("#myTxt").show();
  else
    $("#myTxt").hide();
})
```

Comment: This would just always show it at the beginning, regardless of the initial value.

Comment: He has written 
<option value='0' selected>Other</option>,
to select other as initial value always on page load.

Comment: I agree with @Lain ...In my original codes, the selected one is not always selected...for example, what if someone selected the first option, thus the first option appear a textbox